# How can I add an id to a variable in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**loader.js**

```
$('a').click(function(){
var page = $(this).attr('href');
$("#content").load(page);

return false;
});
```

---

**index.html**

```
<nav>
   <a href="home.html">Home</a>
   <a href="about.html">about</a>
   <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
</nav>

<div id="content">
Content goes here
</div>
<script src="js/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

By using the JS code, all of the links are being loaded into the div.

I want to be able to load specific links into the div and for the rest to open normally.

---

Would it work by adding an **id** to both JS code and href link that I want to be loaded into the div? or/and is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: You can target them via `href`. `$('[href="about.html"], [href="contact.html]').click ()` would add this event to both links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want only some links to load dynamically into your div ?

You could add a class to the links that should be loaded into your div and only trigger your function when a link with this class is clicked.

Note that you could also use an attribute. ( not an id, since an id is supposed to be unique )

```js
$('a.dynamic-loading').click(function(){
var page = $(this).attr('href');
$("#content").load(page);

return false;
});
```

```html
<nav>
   <a href="home.html">Home</a>
   <a href="about.html" class="dynamic-loading">about</a>
   <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
</nav>

<div id="content">
Content goes here
</div>
```

Hope it helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$('nav a').click()` to apply your script only to the links in the `nav` section..

Or better add an specific class selector to the links you want

Script:

```
$('a.page').click(function () {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#content").load(page);

    return false;
});
```

index.html:

```
<nav>
    <a class="page" href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a class="page" href="about.html">about</a>
    <a class="page" href="contact.html">contact</a>
</nav>

<div id="content">
    Content goes here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an ID to the CSS selector.

```js
$('a#loadInContent').click(function() {
  var page = $(this).attr('href');
  $("#content").load(page);

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="about.html">about</a>
  <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
</nav>

<div id="content">
  Content goes here
</div>
<script src='js/loader.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain javascript as well, for us who like that, using the absolute simplest way and add a class to the one's to target

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      getContent(e.target.href,document.querySelector('#content'));
    });
  }
})
function getContent(page,target) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      target.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", page, true);
  xhttp.send();  
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <a class="content" href="home.html">Home</a>
   <a class="content" href="about.html">about</a>
   <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
</nav>

<div id="content">
  Content goes here
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having an issue where I can load via nav targets but cannot load via targets that are inside of the div. Can you help me, again? Thank you!

Comment: @BrianCooper Show me the code that is not working and I'll have a look

Comment: Exactly the one above. Don't get me wrong, your code works perfectly. But now I have added some links inside the div, the ones inside the div don't work and instead open in a new tab, other links (nav) work perfectly.

Comment: @BrianCooper Still I need to see a sample of those links inside the div. Also do note that any content inside the div, links included, will be overwritten since the above code target the div and loads it with the content from the xml request

Comment: I had the class and id renamed to two different names. I changed them back to "content" and that fixed the problem. Now links within the div work just like the ones within nav. Thank you for your time!!

Comment: I meant the links that are loaded into the div via a loaded page. sorry for the mess. Thanks again!